# Use a different charset for some specific requests in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding

I'm now using UTF-8 in my web application, but some clients would POST data in other charsets like GB2312. I can't set the `<globalization requestEncoding="GB2312" />` because it would  affect the whole site.

Can I use a charset for decoding the data for specific requests so that I can get the correct text via `context.Request.Forms` collections?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm struggling with the same problem.